# Python unexpected interpretation of lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I expect the code below to create x, then make a copy of x which i called y, change x and then output y. That is, I expect the lines of code to be run sequentially.

```
x = [10,20,30]
y = x
x[1] = 42
print(y)
```

Instead, y is changed when x is. Why is that, and how should I read the code?
the output is:

```
[10, 42, 30]
```

Comment: `x = y` is simply naming the **same** list `x`and `y`. To name a (shallow) **copy** of the list `y` use: `y = list(x)` or `y = x[:]`

Comment: `y = x.copy()` works too...

Comment: `list.copy` is python3 specific